# How to set rights to all existing and new files of specified directory

Tags: linux, ftp, chmod

I have an Ubuntu server, i have a directory `/testftp/`. In this directory i have many other directories and files in them, how can i set to all existing and new directories and files in this directories rights - `755`?

`/testftp/` group is `testclient`

Thanks!

**upd**
using 
`chmod -R 755 /testftp/` all ok, but when i create/upload new file or directory it has `600` rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following manual pages

```
man chmod
man umask
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod -R 755 /testscript/`

`-R` means recursive and it applies to all sub directories.

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-and-directory-permissions.html. Then u have to set the `umask` value. Have a look into this.

Comment: i have a 600 rights when i upload this files via ftp, maybe i need to change something in ftp config?

Comment: If u r using proftpd then u can change `umask` in `/etc/proftpd.conf`